# How can I disable access to plugin settings in wp admin for other roles

Tags: plugins, user-roles

Hi I have a website where people can register a new account and access the site dashboard(wp-admin). But these users can also access settings of other plugins on my site. Is there a way to disable access for a certain role(contributers and authers) on my website.

I am pretty much novice in these things so hope anyone will help me in easy manner.
Thank You.

[image: In admin view]
[image: Insubscriber view]
[image: Contributer view]

Comment: Ehm, normally only an admin can do such, you must do some terrible wrong. Please take a look here in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator) Almost would say, install this [user switch](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/) and see what your users can see.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default user role to subscriber. So that the new user will not have access to the plugins.

You can set the default user role here.

[image]

Comment: Well I thought of that but my default role is contributer since I want them to be able to write posts. And for editors and authors I want to limit the user permissions and access to plugins.

Comment: @MilanMuhammed I just have check, the editors and authors doens't have access to plugins and users. But if you want to give them those permissions, you can do so by using the following plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Capability+Manager+Enhanced/

Comment: Can I edit permissions too with that plugin which are already given?

Comment: @MilanMuhammed yes you can, but you need to edit those permission from the administrator role.

Comment: I edited the permissions but the plugin options still appear for those users

Comment: Show the screenshots.

Comment: I updated the question.